# C++ instantiating a class within a method, then altering member variables from a different method?

Tags: c++, class

Say I have a method, and within that method it instantiates a Person class:

```
void methodA()
{
    Person personObject;
}
```

How would I access that object's methods from within another method? I.e. something like:

```
void methodB()
{
    personObject.someMethod();
}
```

I realise it's a painfully nooby question :P

Comment: You're not calling `methodB`. When you do, `methodA` will have finished and the `Person` you made is destructed. If you need a `Person` as data in your class, make it a member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a reference to the other function.

```
void methodB(Person &personObject)
{
    personObject.someMethod();
}

void methodA()
{
    Person personObject;
    methodB(personObject);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify methodB's personObject could be called anything at all.  The name doesn't need to match that of methodA.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The first `Person` object is a local object and disappears once outside the scope of the function.  You'd need to make it part of the class for other methods to view it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make personObject a member of the class. Also, if you must create personObject in methodA, rather than having it initialized in the constructor, then you'll need to dynamically create the object with new.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
        : personObject(0)
    {
    }
    ~MyClass() 
    {
        delete personObject;
    }
    void methodA()
    {
        personObject = new Person();
    }
    void methodB()
    {
        personObject->someMethod();
    }
private:
    Person* personObject;
};
```

Comment: Of course, one needs to implement the copy-constructor and assignment operator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want the `personObject` to be a member variable of your class:

```
class SomeClass {
   Person personObject;
public:
   void methodA();
   void methodB();
};

void SomeClass::methodA() {
    personObject = Person(123);
}

void SomeClass::methodB() {
    personObject.someMethod();
}
```